# how to select, not expanded dropdownlists with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui

I m using kendo UI dropdownlist. But solutions for standard select element can help too.

I had tried

```
$('select:not(aria-expanded)')
$('select:not(aria-expanded=true)') // syntax error
$('select:not(expanded)')
$('select:not([aria-expanded=true])')
$('select:not([expanded=true])')
```

none of these work correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap the attribute inside square brackets `[ ]`:

```
$('select:not([aria-expanded=true])')
```

Comment: thanks for fast answer but still select expanded and not expanded dropdowns

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about how to focus on the select dropdown list [then use the methods that are apart of the api for the dropdown list](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/dropdownlist#methods-focus).

```
<script>
    $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList();
    var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList");
    dropdownlist.focus();
</script>
```

**update**

[Here is how you get the value](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/dropdownlist#methods-value) of a Kendo dropdownlist using jquery:

```
<script>
    var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList");
    var value = dropdownlist.value();
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. For example I have 5 dropdownlist and when first dropdown is expanded, I want to get objects of other 4 dropdownlist with jquery. Sorry for my English.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am still unclear on what you want to do. In my answer, click the link I addded. It is the full documentation for the Javascript / jQuery API for the Kendo dropdownlist. Please try to better describe your issue.